# proper permissions for a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Nginx is giving me a 403 Forbidden error.  It looks like my permissions are wrong.  This is what I have going on my local machine:

```
  drwx------ 13 sean sean  4096 2010-07-10 13:17 .
  drwxr-xr-x 41 sean sean  4096 2010-07-13 17:55 ..
  drwx------  6 sean sean  4096 2010-07-09 16:45 app
  drwx------  5 sean sean  4096 2010-07-13 17:54 config
  drwx------  3 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:44 db
  drwx------  2 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 doc
  drwx------  3 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 lib
  drwx------  2 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 log
  drwx------  5 sean sean  4096 2010-07-10 20:28 public
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean   307 2010-06-20 14:31 Rakefile
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 10011 2010-06-20 14:31 README
  drwx------  3 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 script
  drwx------  7 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 test
  drwx------  6 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 tmp
  drwx------  3 sean sean  4096 2010-06-20 14:31 vendor
```

/public

```
  drwx------  5 sean sean 4096 2010-07-10 20:28 .
  drwx------ 13 sean sean 4096 2010-07-10 13:17 ..
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean  947 2010-06-20 14:31 404.html
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean  930 2010-06-20 14:31 422.html
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean  948 2010-06-20 14:31 500.html
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean    0 2010-06-20 14:31 favicon.ico
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-06-20 14:31 images
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-06-20 14:31 javascripts
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean  204 2010-06-20 14:31 robots.txt
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-07-09 09:58 stylesheets
```

/config

```
  drwx------  5 sean sean 4096 2010-07-13 17:54 .
  drwx------ 13 sean sean 4096 2010-07-10 13:17 ..
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 2795 2010-06-20 14:31 boot.rb
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 1351 2010-07-13 17:54 database.yml
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 2133 2010-07-10 12:49 environment.rb
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 2074 2010-07-09 16:40 environment.rb~
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-07-10 12:58 environments
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-07-10 12:54 initializers
  drwx------  2 sean sean 4096 2010-06-20 14:31 locales
  -rwxr-xr-x  1 sean sean 2212 2010-07-13 17:54 routes.rb
```

What is the best way to set permissions?

```
 server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  name.org;
    root /path/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
  }
```

Comment: Show us your nginx config. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: It is a simple passenger-nginx setup

I was able to create a simple hello world app on my server.  When I scp my actual source code, I got a 403 error when attempting to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `chmod -R 755 public/` that will make public readable.

Comment: Well it will run if I set it like this:
directory: drwxr-xr-x
file: -rw-r--r--

Any objections?  Should some files and directories have different permissions?